# Can a non-practicing Jew give his only tefilin away as a gift?

Tags: halacha, tefilin, gifts

What is the halacha behind gifting tefilin? What is the halacha of receiving tefilin? Can a Jew gift his only pair of tefilin if he does not use it and can another Jew accept a gift which leaves the receiver without any tefilin?

Comment: I think the details in the original question actually added some useful background. Not sure editing them out is really that helpful here.

Comment: Baruch, your original question was clearly a request for a practical ruling, which is not something we can offer. Your current version is not, and looks like a valid question (though it could do with some more details), but is not the same essential question as your original one, since this version is about what the giver is allowed to do, while you were previously asking what the receiver was allowed to do. If this is what you want, fine. If not, I'd encourage you to rewrite the original question to be not asking for a ruling, along the lines of ...

Comment: ... "Is it permissible to receive, as a gift, the only pair of tefilin owned by a Jewish man who says that he never uses them?" Either way, the question will be most valuable if you also include reasoning about why you think the action in question may or may not be allowed.

Comment: Looks like you guys already closed the post. I just asked my rabbi and he said if I had none it would be OK but the giver always could have a change of heart and so I cannot have 2 while he has zero and make it impossible for him to do the mitzvah for my simple convenience. It would have been cool to get the halacha behind it but it seems like it's causing a stir here =)

Comment: @Baruch, the question can be reopened, but it has to be reworded a bit. I liked the first revision, that had the background and a lot of relevant information, but in order to maintain order around here, we have to make good and certain that nobody uses this site as a place for psak halacha. Why don't you [edit] your question a little more, and we'll see about reopening it? (you already have 2/5 required votes to reopen)

Comment: We've been discussing this in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) as well; if you don't want to join the discussion, you can read about it, starting from around [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19671629#19671629)

Answer (score 2):

Like I said in a [comment on the question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52961/can-a-non-practicing-jew-give-his-only-tefilin-away-as-a-gift#comment139971_52961), I don't know if halacha discusses this question, but it just feels like a bad idea to burn bridges like that. Even if the tefillin aren't in use *right now*, but if they're given away, then the opportunity to start using them again is gone.

Some take a very *[Toy Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story)* view* of mitzvah objects, that it's "sad" or "unfortunate" that a pair of tefillin or a tallis hasn't been in use (*which might or might not have some support in [certain minhagim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3151/5323)*), I think it's even sadder when *a Jew* doesn't do an easy mitzvah, and doesn't care to the point of giving away the mitzva object to be used by another.

---

* *that "toys deeply want children to play with them, and that this desire drives their hopes, fears, and actions."* ~[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story)

Comment: See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53002/can-one-adopt-a-non-jewish-child-and-not-convert-him-her#comment140139_53009 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53002/can-one-adopt-a-non-jewish-child-and-not-convert-him-her#comment140147_53009

Comment: Shokhet, could you insert the revision date for Wikipedia in case your quote from there is deleted from the source article?